# SSL SSLv2 client hello - handshake failure

Tags: java, ssl

I am stuck with below SSL exception:

```
ERROR STDERR - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
2016-10-21 07:26:37,502 [http-10.8.184.11-8080-14] ERROR STDERR - at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
2016-10-21 07:26:37,502 [http-10.8.184.11-8080-14] ERROR STDERR - at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:136)
2016-10-21 07:26:37,502 [http-10.8.184.11-8080-14] ERROR STDERR - at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1822)
```

**SSL debug logs says below:**

```
INFO STDOUT - http-10.8.184.11-8080-14, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 81
2016-10-21 07:26:37,499 [http-10.8.184.11-8080-14] INFO STDOUT - http-10.8.184.11-8080-14, WRITE: SSLv2 client hello message, length = 110
2016-10-21 07:26:37,501 [http-10.8.184.11-8080-14] INFO STDOUT - http-10.8.184.11-8080-14, READ: Unknown-3.3 Alert, length = 2
2016-10-21 07:26:37,501 [http-10.8.184.11-8080-14] INFO STDOUT - http-10.8.184.11-8080-14
2016-10-21 07:26:37,501 [http-10.8.184.11-8080-14] INFO STDOUT - , RECV TLSv1 ALERT: 
2016-10-21 07:26:37,501 [http-10.8.184.11-8080-14] INFO STDOUT - fatal, 
2016-10-21 07:26:37,501 [http-10.8.184.11-8080-14] INFO STDOUT - handshake_failure
2016-10-21 07:26:37,501 [http-10.8.184.11-8080-14] INFO STDOUT - http-10.8.184.11-8080-14, called closeSocket()
2016-10-21 07:26:37,501 [http-10.8.184.11-8080-14] INFO STDOUT - http-10.8.184.11-8080-14, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
2016-10-21 07:26:37,502 [http-10.8.184.11-8080-14] INFO STDOUT - http-10.8.184.11-8080-14, called close()
2016-10-21 07:26:37,502 [http-10.8.184.11-8080-14] INFO STDOUT - http-10.8.184.11-8080-14, called closeInternal(true)
2016-10-21 07:26:37,502 [http-10.8.184.11-8080-14] ERROR STDERR - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
2016-10-21 07:26:37,502 [http-10.8.184.11-8080-14] ERROR STDERR - at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
2016-10-21 07:26:37,502 [http-10.8.184.11-8080-14] ERROR STDERR - at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:136)
```

Comment: Are you using a self signed certificate? Seems like you are sending request against `http` insted of `https`, can we have a look at a code snippet? what is the application type? is it standard java, ee or android?

Comment: There exist already many many questions about such handshake failure. Please check out these question and if you don't find the answer there post enough information which make it clear how your question differs from all these others and why the others don't solve your problem. Also, use proper formatting instead of the current dump if you want others to kindly help you for free.

Answer (score 1):

You are running some ancient version of Java which still supports the `SSLv2ClientHello`, and the server refuses to accept it. You should remove `SSLv2ClientHello`from the enabled protocols before connecting.